# Graphing Complex Equation With Variable Coefficients!

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

**Let $\omega$ $=$ $-\frac{1}{2}$+$i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ (Where $i=\sqrt-1$).Consider S , the set of all complex numbers in the Argand Plane of the form $$a+b\omega +c \omega^2  . \forall (a,b,c) \in [0,1]$$  Plot the area covered by S**

> I honestly have the knowledge level of a school student in complex no. I honestly dont know how varying a,b,c will give me any shape however the solution mentions theres an hexagon, i can prove that I tried  multiplying the given equation ($a+b\omega +c \omega^2$) with its conjugate to at least get some relation since its a known result but a,b,c varying over [0,1] still makes it confusing. Will appreciate any help with this problem, thanks!

Comment: For clarity, you meant $\omega=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ did you? And in your main expression, do you intend the $\dots$ to indicate the sum goes on for ever with arbitrarily high powers of $\omega$, or do you just mean the three terms you have given?

Comment: @DavidSheard Yes i meant to put an 'i' there and the expression just stops at the three terms, still learning how to use latex, extremely sorry

Comment: Start from $a = b = c = 0$. If you increase $a$ from $0$ to $1$, you get a line segment from $0$ to $1$. If you increase $b$ from $0$ to $1$ for each $a$, the line segment will move at $120^\circ$ wrt $x$-axis and spread out a rhombus with vertices at $0,1,1+\omega,\omega$. If you increase $c$ from $0$ to $1$ for each $(a,b)$, the rhombus will move at $-120^\circ$ wrt $x$-axis and spread out a regular hexagon with side $1$.

Comment: Just for calibration, do you know (i) how to plot the three numbers $1$, $\omega$, $\omega^2$; (ii) how to plot $au + bv$ if $u$ and $v$ are complex and $0 \leq a, b \leq 1$?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes I do know how to plot $1, \omega , \omega^2$ but I dont know the latter, it makes me tough to visualize how variation of a,b  will vary the circumference points although :(

Comment: @achillehui This does help me visualize it abit but how do we know for sure that the points connecting the vertices would be a uniform straight line and not some curve?

Comment: There's a parallelogram law for vector addition that explains why if $u$ and $v$ are vectors (e.g., complex numbers), then the set of vectors of the form $u + tv$ with $t$ real is the line through $u$ in the direction of $v$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Preliminaries on convex hulls of points

Here is a very useful geometric fact which doesn't really have anything to do with complex numbers, just the geometry of the plane, but I'll phrase it using complex numbers.

**Fact 1:** Given points $z_1,\dots,z_n\in\mathbb{C}$, the set $$\{a_1z_1+\cdots+a_nz_n\mid a_1,\dots, a_n\in[0,1]\;\textrm{and}\;a_1+\cdots+a_n=1\}$$ is the *convex hull* of the points $z_1,\dots,z_n$.

[image]

To get an idea for why this is true, you could think of $$\frac{a_1z_1+\cdots+a_nz_n}{a_1+\cdots+a_n}$$ as a weighted average of the points $z_1,\dots,z_n$, and the average of a collection of points has to lie "between them" in some sense.

We can use this fact to prove a closely related fact.

**Fact 2:** Given points $z_1,\dots,z_n\in\mathbb{C}$, the set $$\{a_1z_1+\cdots+a_nz_n\mid a_1,\dots, a_n\in[0,1]\;\textrm{and}\;a_1+\cdots+a_n\le1\}$$ is the *convex hull* of the points $z_1,\dots,z_n$ together with the point $0$.

Notice the only difference is we allow an inequality in the set, and now our convex hull includes the origin. To see this follows from the first fact, write $z_0=0$, and $a_0=1-(a_1+\cdots+a_n)\in[0,1]$, then $$\begin{aligned}\{a_1z_1+&\cdots+a_nz_n\mid a_1,\dots, a_n\in[0,1]\;\textrm{and}\;a_1+\cdots+a_n\le1\}=\\ &\{a_0z_0+a_1z_1+\cdots+a_nz_n\mid a_0,a_1,\dots, a_n\in[0,1]\;\textrm{and}\;a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_n=1\}.\end{aligned}$$

### Solving the problem

Your expression in the question is not exactly the same as that given in the facts above, because the coefficients $a$, $b$ and $c$ could sum to more than 1. But we can easily fix this.

First **assume** that $a\le b\le c$, then we can rewrite $$a+b\omega+c\omega^2=a(1+\omega+\omega^2)+(b-a)(\omega+\omega^2)+(c-b)\omega^2.$$
Notice that this first term is zero since $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$, and that by our assumption $b-a,c-b\in[0,1]$. Thus rewriting $z_1=\omega+\omega^2$ and $z_2=\omega^2$, and $a_1=b-a$ and $a_2=c-b$, we can apply Fact 2 (because $a_1+a_2=c-a\le 1$. This implies that the set of points $$a+b\omega+c\omega^2\;\forall a,b,c\in[0,1]\;\textrm{such that}\;a\le b\le c$$ is the convex hull of the points $0$, $\omega+\omega^2$, and $\omega^2$.

[image]

Now if we repeat this with all 6 possible orderings of $a$, $b$, and $c$, we get 6 similar pictures which all combine to give the regular hexagon with vertices $1,1+\omega,\omega,\omega+\omega^2,\omega^2,\omega^2+1$, which is the set $S$ you were after.

[image]

Comment: Wonderfully explained and a beautiful solution! Thank you so much.